# Laravel 5 : database relation query using with

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

User -> Has many question
Question -> Has many answer

I want to show one user questions information with latest answer for each question

```
$questions = Question::select('id','user_id',
            'title','video','status','created_at')
            ->where('user_id','=',$user->id)
            ->where('status','>=','2')
            ->with([
                'user' => function($query){
                    $query->select('id','name','picture');
                },
                'answers' => function($query){
                    $query->select('id','question_id','user_id','answer','created_at',DB::raw('count(*) as answer_count'))
                    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();

                },
            ])->get();
```

here I did not get answer for each question. I got answer for all questions submitted by the user

can you help me please? how to put **where questions id for answer**

## Expected output:

```
User [id, name, and so on ] -> 
question [
    ['id', 'title' ..]->Answer['id','question_id',etc ],
    ['id', 'title' ..]->Answer['id','question_id',etc ]
]
```

[image] [image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$questions = Question::select('id','user_id','title','video','status','created_at')->with([
            'user' => function($query){
                $query->select('id','name','picture');
            }
        ])->where('status','>=','2')->get();

        foreach($questions as $question)
        {
            $question_data[] = [
                'id' => $question->id,
                'title' => $question->title,
                'video' => $question->video,
                'user_id' => $question->user_id,
                'status' => $question->status,
                'created_at' => $question->created_at->toDateTimeString(),
                'thumbnail' => $question->thumbnail,
                'user' => [
                    'id' => $question->user->id,
                    'name' => $question->user->name,
                    'picture' => $question->user->picture
                ],
                'answers' => 
                $question->answers()->select('video','question_id','user_id','created_at','thumbnail')
                ->with([
                    'user' => function($query){
                        $query->select('id','name','picture');
                    }
                ])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first()];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with fetching user with their questions and the answers to them, not with the questions themselves, to get the expected output:

```
$user = User::select('id','name','picture')->with([
            'questions' => function($query){
                $query->select('id','user_id','title','video','status','created_at');
                $query->where('status','>=','2');
            },
            'questions.answers' => function($query){
                $query->select('id','question_id','user_id','answer','created_at',DB::raw('count(*) as answer_count'));
                $query->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();

            },
        ])->findOrFail($user_id);
```

Now you should be able to get all questions asked by given user and the latest answer to them with the following:

```
foreach($user->questions as $question) {
  $answer = $question->answers;
}
```

Comment: this query displays only overall the latest answer(latest answer for the user's question) . I want the latest answer for each question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The query above will give you user object, all questions of given user and latest answer for each of their question. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: yes. all questions of given user and latest answer for each of their question

Comment: THis is what the query above should give you. How are you accessing the data?

Comment: all questions of given user and latest answer for each question. not each user

Comment: I've updated the answer, now you'll get a single user object with related questions and their latest answer

Comment: still am getting latest answer of the user.

Comment: {"id":4,"name":"Subakaran Karuppuchamy","picture":"","questions":[{"id":2,"user_id":4,"title":"what is the command for remove file in unix","video":"Ni1EmK6UujhjSK65ULRVJZkAiu5pyx4z77Jkbs7noRz2kVylN7i7DKs2KnaqA0nz6GX27IyQQ2UF4VuK.mp4","status":2,"created_at":"2016-07-31 08:34:37","answers":[{"id":1,"question_id":2,"user_id":4,"answer":"it will be discussed later","created_at":"2016-08-27 06:55:56","answer_count":5}]},

Comment: this user has two question. but it displays only one question and one latest answer among of two question's answer

Comment: Make sure the other question has status >= 2 as that's one of the constraints in the query

Comment: yes have. I have updated the question( attached database structure with screen-capture )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122608/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-suba).